# jquery.minicolors.js with opacity

Tags: joomla-3.x, development, jquery

I know that the jquery.minicolors.js used in the color input field support the opacity and rgba as option. Is it possible to use them in the color input field?

This is the default Joomla! color picker (input color field type) [image] 
and I would like to also have the opacity option [image].

Is it possible?

Thanks

Comment: @fruppel Just didn't mention that I am trying to add this color input field type in a plugin that I am developing. Sorry

Comment: Are you using it with `JForm` or just plain HTML (`<input type="color"...`)?

Comment: ahh, I finally get what you want to do now. A feature like this is relatively big. I'd suggest going to your Joomla Global Config, setting **Debug System** to **On**. Open the jQuery.minicolours.js (the ubcompressed version) and start messing round with the code a little to see what you can do. Come back when you have more of a coding related issue

Comment: @Rene Korss I am using it with `JForm`. Thanks

Comment: Then you have to [create custom form field type](https://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_custom_form_field_type) which uses jquery.minicolors.

Comment: @Rene Korss Do you think it's preferable (possible) to extend the existing color field or `JFormField` itself?

Comment: I would definately extend `JFormFieldColor` and only override `getInput` method to remove regular colorpicker settings and replace them with custom ones. I actually made it already, bu I can't answer this question before it is reopened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As said in comment, I would extend `JFormFieldColor` and override `getInput` method.

As it turned out, Joomla! current jQuery minicolor plugin is outdated, so you should include your own. There is [PR](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/pull/7602) for improving it and allowing opacity picker. Until it's not merged and published with new version, you should use below code.

You can use it likes this:

```
<field 
   name="color" 
   type="minicolor"
   label="Choose color"
   format="rgb"
   opacity="0.5" />
```

**minicolor.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * Custom Joomla! form field to generate minicolors input with optional opacity slider
 *
 * NOTE: replace PATH_TO_CUSTOM_MINICOLORS with path to minicolors files. See below.
 */

// Check to ensure this file is included in Joomla!
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');

JFormHelper::loadFieldClass('color');

class JFormFieldMinicolor extends JFormFieldColor {

  protected $type = 'Minicolor';

  /**
   * Method to get the field input markup.
   *
   * @return  string  The field input markup.
   *
   * @since   11.3
   */
  protected function getInput()
  {
    // Translate placeholder text
    $hint = $this->translateHint ? JText::_($this->hint) : $this->hint;

    // Control value can be: hue (default), saturation, brightness, wheel
    $control = $this->control;

    // Valid options are hex and rgb.
    $format  = $this->element['format'];

    // Set to true to enable the opacity slider.
    $opacity = $this->element['opacity'];

    // Position of the panel can be: right (default), left, top or bottom
    $position = ' data-position="' . $this->position . '"';

    $onchange  = !empty($this->onchange) ? ' onchange="' . $this->onchange . '"' : '';
    $class     = $this->class;
    $required  = $this->required ? ' required aria-required="true"' : '';
    $disabled  = $this->disabled ? ' disabled' : '';
    $autofocus = $this->autofocus ? ' autofocus' : '';

    $color = strtolower($this->value);

    if (!$color || in_array($color, array('none', 'transparent')))
    {
      $color = 'none';
    }

    $class        = ' class="' . trim('minicolors ' . $class) . '"';
    $control      = $control ? ' data-control="' . $control . '"' : '';
    $format       = $format ? ' data-format="' . $format . '"' : '';
    $opacity      = $opacity ? ' data-opacity="' . $opacity . '"' : '';
    $readonly     = $this->readonly ? ' readonly' : '';
    $hint         = $hint ? ' placeholder="' . $hint . '"' : ' placeholder="rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)"';
    $autocomplete = !$this->autocomplete ? ' autocomplete="off"' : '';

    // Including fallback code for HTML5 non supported browsers.
    JHtml::_('jquery.framework');
    JHtml::_('script', 'system/html5fallback.js', false, true);

    // Include jQuery
    JHtml::_('jquery.framework');

    // We must include our custom minicolors, since Joomla! has outdated version
    // See: https://github.com/claviska/jquery-minicolors/
    JHtml::_('script', 'PATH_TO_CUSTOM_MINICOLORS/jquery.minicolors.min.js', false, true);
    JHtml::_('stylesheet', 'PATH_TO_CUSTOM_MINICOLORS/jquery.minicolors.css', false, true);

    JFactory::getDocument()->addScriptDeclaration("
        jQuery(document).ready(function (){
          jQuery('input.minicolors').each(function() {
            jQuery(this).minicolors({
              control: jQuery(this).attr('data-control') || 'hue',
              position: jQuery(this).attr('data-position') || 'right',
              format: jQuery(this).attr('data-format') || 'hex',
              opacity: jQuery(this).attr('data-opacity') || false,
              theme: 'bootstrap'
            });
          });
        });
      "
    );

    return '<input type="text" name="' . $this->name . '" id="' . $this->id . '"' . ' value="'
      . htmlspecialchars($color, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8') . '"' . $hint . $class . $position . $control . $format . $opacity
      . $readonly . $disabled . $required . $onchange . $autocomplete . $autofocus . '/>';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With the latest Joomla! the minicolor plugin has been updated and it's easy to achieve this without having to add the above multicolor.php. Just adjust your XML field to;

```
<field 
   name="YourCustomFieldName" 
   type="color"
   label="Choose color"
   format="rgb"
   description="" />
```

If you want to add the opacity effect, change the format command to; format="rgba"

The color field box in your extension option(s) will generate the necessary rgb and opacity code that you'll use in your frontend PHP structure.

That's it! This 'color' XML command is still not documented within the Joomla! docs... What a shame!